# Updating complex model binding EF5 ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to update my entities and their related data. Using Lazyloading..

I have the following entity models

```
public class Config
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DataField> DataFields { get; set; }
}

public class DataField
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Config")]
    public Int32 ConfigId { get; set; }

    public virtual Config Config { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(1000)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

With the corresponding view models. I've stripped them down, removed validations and such.

```
public class ConfigViewModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public IList<DataFieldViewModel> DataFields { get; set; }

    public ConfigModel()
    {
        DataFields = new List<DataFieldViewModel>();
    }
}
public class DataFieldViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my Edit.cshtml form I dynamically add new datafields, and when I post the form, they are properly deserialised to ConfigViewModel.DataFields. So long everything is working.
But how do I convert these models, and update the entitymodels?
If I post new datafields, their id's will be 0, and they should be added, but the ones that already have an Id, should be updated..
I don't know how to do this, and can't find anything related, or that I could understand.

I have the following in my ConfigController.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ConfigViewModel model)
{
    try
    {       
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        var config = uow.Repository<Entity.Models.Config>().FindById(model.Id);

        config.Name = model.Name;

        // Do something with the datafields
        // config.DataFields

        uow.Repository<Entity.Models.Config>().Edit(config);
        uow.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

In my repository I have:

```
public void Edit(TEntity entity)
{
    var entry = Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

My Edit.cshtml form looks like

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.DataFields.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>                         
        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DataFields[i].Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataFields[i].Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.DataFields[i].Type)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a couple of things are happening here.

If I understand your data structures correctly, you have a `Config` object that has zero or more `DataField` objects associated with it.

The Edit page of your application for editing `Config` objects allows you to add *new* `DataField` items **or** *modify existing* `DataField` items.

I'm assuming that in the commented section of your example:

```
// Do Something with the DataFields
// config.DataFields
```

that you're translating the View Models back to your domain objects.

Now I'm going to assume that you are using a per-request lifetime for the `DbContext`, as that's most typical in these scenarios. So, on each web request, a new `DbContext` is instantiated as part of the instantiation chain of the MVC Controller and its dependencies (e.g. services, repositories, unit of work, etc.). So on this new request for editing `Config` objects, the `DbContext` is empty—it has no knowledge of any objects because it's a brand new `DbContext`.

At this point, you need to `Attach` the `Config` entity to the `DbContext` so that the `DbContext` will start tracking it. If anything changed about the `Config` entity (e.g. was the name changed, or were new `DataField` objects added to the collection?), you will need to set the state of the entity within the `DbContext` to `Modified` (this you have done in your example above).

Attaching the `Config` entity to the `DbContext` will also result in attaching all the related `DataField` objects that are referenced by the edited `Config` entity. But there's a slight wrinkle. You will need to tell the `DbContext` which entities are new, and which are modified. You can easily tell new entities from modified entities because the `DataField.Id` property will be 0. But how do you tell if an existing `DataField` entity has been returned unchanged? This is important, because simply attaching the `DataField` entities to the `DbContext` puts them in an `Unmodified` state within the context. So, if there were any changes on an existing entity, those changes would not be persisted when committing the context.

A naive approach to solve this problem would entail setting all `DataField` entities whose `Id` property is non-zero to the `Modified` state. This will increase load on the database (but for a small application, this will be negligible). However, if you have any triggers or some other mechanism for auditing when records are created or updated, this is not a good solution. Assuming you are not performing auditing, the naive approach may work well:

```
public void Edit(TEntity config)
{
    Context.Attach<TEntity>(config);
    Context.Entry<TEntity>(config).State = EntityState.Modified;

    foreach(var df in config.DataFields)
    {
        Context.Entry<DataField>(df).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // I noticed you never saved the changes to the DbContext. Do you need
    // to do this here, or are you doing it with your UOW somewhere else??
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Again, this is a naive approach that should generally work well for small applications. At the very least, it should give you a better idea of the kinds of things you need to be aware of when working with Entity Framework in a disconnected N-Tier scenario.

Also, I highly recommend you check out the following books:

- [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260)
- [Programming Entity Framework: DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969)
- [Programming Entity Framework: Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312942)

Each of those books discusses the scenario you're talking about. You may want to start with the Code First book since you are using code first.

HTH